# Unable to see controller added to UITabBar programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I added 2 tabBar items from storyboard and one UITabBarItem - *Menu* programmatically. I am successfully able to open the controllers corresponding to tabBarItems which I created using storyboard. However, when I click on "Menu" a blank black screen appears,

```
@objc public class MainScreenTabsController : UITabBarController {
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tabController = MyViewController()
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Menu", image: UIImage(named: "more-options.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "more-options"))
    tabController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    var array = self.viewControllers
    array?.append(tabController)
    self.viewControllers = array
}

public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true;
}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
}
```

I followed couple of tutorials for adding tab bar item but all of them had the code I wrote. Am I missing out something very basic?
[image: The three dots represent menu. The word menu is not included because in the real code I gave a blank string]

EDIT:

Class for Menu Controller

```
@objc public class MyViewController:UIViewController {

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
}
```

Comment: show back screen (Menu) controller code

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Edited the question

Comment: I don't think MyViewController() will give you InstantiatedViewController

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I followed the tutorial - http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/

Comment: `MyViewController` not working it should inherit  tabbar controller

Comment: @NazmulHasan Tried inheriting tabbarController as well. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is doing exactly what your code is telling it to do. You are creating an instance of `MyViewController` and adding it to the `UITabBarController`'s array of View Controllers.

Your `MyViewController` class file simply defines a blank, black view.

I'm guessing you created a ViewController in your Storyboard that you want to use as `MyViewController`? If so, you need to instantiate that from the storyboard.

When you're editing your storyboard, assign the `MyViewController` class to the VC you want to use, and *also* give it a `Storyboard ID` - such as `MyVC`. Then, edit your `viewDidLoad` function to this:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // wrong way
    //  let tabController = MyViewController()

    if let tabController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC") as? MyViewController {

        let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Menu", image: UIImage(named: "more-options.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "more-options"))
        tabController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
        var array = self.viewControllers
        array?.append(tabController)
        self.viewControllers = array

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I create the controller in storyboard. Why did you write tabBarItem and other declarations within a bracket? When I do it, I get an error. Now, I am instantiating using 
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Utility", bundle: nil)
let tabController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController and other lines of code follow this. But still the screen is blank.

Comment: The code "within brackets" is inside an `if let` construct, which helps avoid forced-unwrapping and nil optionals. Put a breakpoint on your `let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Utility", bundle: nil)` line and step through, checking the values of the variables / objects you are creating. See if something is failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and explanation. The solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating the ViewController programatically ie. without nib/storyboard, you are responsible for instantiating a UIView object and setting the view property of the view controller. to do that implement the [loadView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) method and assign the view object to view property of the viewController. then you can add custom views to the view object, check the code below.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        // super.loadView()   // DO NOT CALL SUPER

        //create view
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        //Add a custom view with red color
        let customView = UIView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(customView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
             customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
             customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
             customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)]
        )
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

It would be good to use Storyboard/Nib for this purpose as you can easily configure custom views/controls using the autolayout in interface builder rather than doing it programmatically. :)

**Edit:**

if your'e using storyboard then instantiate view controller like given in below code

```
class MainScreenTabsController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let tabController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController //if using storyboard 
        let icon = UITabBarItem(title: "Menu", UIImage(named: "more-options.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "more-options")))
        tabController.tabBarItem = icon
        var controllers = self.viewControllers
        controllers?.append(tabController)
        self.setViewControllers(controllers!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created UIViewController using a storyboard. and then linked that with my class

Comment: have you tried the code without storyboard? if you use storyboard then you need to instantiate view controller using code like                                                     let tabController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController